GitHub: Links broken in PDFs?
tl;dr I have PDFs in my local repo. The PDFs all have various hyperlinks in them. In the local files, when I hover over a link, I get the option to open that link in a web browser, as expected. When I push them to the remote repo on GitHub, however, the corresponding PDFs on GitHub do not recognize the links as links. They are just formatted text, and hovering over them does not give the option to open the web page that they are supposed to link to. Is this expected behavior?
Deets

I created a bunch of slide decks using Google Slides and Safari.
The decks all had hyperlinks in them on at least one slide each.
I downloaded the decks using the File -> Download as PDF feature of Google Slides.
I uploaded the PDFs to GitHub.
I noticed that the links did not work on GitHub.
I checked the local files and the links didn't work there either. D'oh.
Poking around on the interwebs, I discovered that links in Google Slides break unless downloaded using Chrome. There's probably more to it than that, but I don't care enough about Google Slides, Safari, Chrome, etc. to investigate more deeply; suffice it to say that I re-downloaded all the decks as PDFs using Chrome, and verified that in the newly downloaded files, the links were copacetic.
I replaced the PDFs in the local repo with the newly-downloaded PDFs, renaming them to the same names as the original PDFs.
git did not recognize them as updated files despite the fact that their modification date changed in the MacOS finder.
I tried the suggestions in Why doesn't git recognize that my file has been changed, therefore git add not working and Git is not picking up my changed files, but they availed not.
I touched a file to see whether that would be sufficient to get git to see it as modified. It wasn't.
I renamed the files to something different, git rmed the original files, and did a git add of the new files and a git commit and git push. Then I renamed the files back to their original names, and did the whole git rm git add git commit and git push thing again.
The links are still broken on GitHub.
I duplicated one of the slide decks, gave it a different name, added it to the local repo, commited, pushed. The links are fine locally; they are not functional as links on GitHub.

So after all this, I'm confused about whether GitHub just doesn't render links in PDFs uploaded there, or whether something about the way in which I originally downloaded the files (using Safari, with non-functioning links) is preventing git/github from correctly recognizing that the newly downloaded PDFs (using Chrome, with functioning links) are different from the originally uploaded files. Any advice?
(And out of curiosity, why doesn't git recognize date modified as an indication that the file has changed? Or perhaps that's a separate question.)
